# how to set UITableViewCell background tranparent?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

how to set UITableViewCell background tranparent?

I am trying

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But that is giving black color.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please view this post:
[How to create a UITableViewCell with a transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008246/how-to-create-a-uitableviewcell-with-a-transparent-background)

Comment: When I am using that code, it give me an error: expected expression before 'UIView'

Comment: Perhaps you can repost a few lines around the code where you see the error. Your response does not help us help you.

Comment: Make sure that you have `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in your .h file.

Comment: I have also written #import statement.