# How can i have more than one cell in a table view row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have seen apps that have table views that have rows that contain 2 or 3 cells. Something like the following:

```
| 3 cells in one row        |

/-------\ /-------\ /-------\
|do this| |  do   | |do smth|   <--- table view row that contains 3 cells
|       | | that  | | else  |
\-------/ \-------/ \-------/
```

When you click on a cell they behave exactly like a cell and have different events. Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to use some trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they don't have to look like cells, I would use 3 Buttons in a custom UITableViewCell. They also get blue if you tap on them.

Comment: Adding buttons seems ok but I don't know if I can make the container cell have transparent background so the buttons look like real cells. Gonna try out.

Comment: Ah you want them to look real. Than I've another Idea. Try to place 3 UITableviews side by side and synchronize their movement. ;-)

Comment: Tables and table cells can have transparent backgrounds, at the expense of scrolling performance.

Answer (score 5):

Those aren't actually separate cells. A UITableView can only contain rows, not columns. But each cell can be laid out with its content in three equal-sized areas, thereby mimicking a real grid of content.

Answer (score 0):

Adding buttons and then using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008246/how-to-create-a-uitableviewcell-with-a-transparent-background) seems to be the easiest way. Although the `initWithFrame:CGRectZero` looks hacky, it works.