# How to make a UITableView as transparent one?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, opacity, background-color

In my application, i am presenting an UITableViewController class (Grouped style) to the user for the particular scenario. I want to show the table view's cells only. The background should be transparent so that the user can see the previous page.

I tried with the following codes in `viewDidLoad` method of the table view controller. But they are not working..

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

self.tableView.opaque = NO;

self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Is it possible to show the cells with a dimmed background?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what do you mean by dimmed background? light grey color or something ?

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean by displaying previous page on tableview's background to user !!

Comment: I want the background like [link] (http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=uisearchdisplaycontroller&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&tbm=isch&tbnid=qtDucy4yKONDcM:&imgrefurl=http://www.cocoachina.com/iphonedev/sdk/2009/0726/327.html&docid=MaLPkY5XsNHBtM&w=414&h=770&ei=7E5vTv_RLcGyrAer29ShBw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=184&vpy=246&dur=4923&hovh=306&hovw=164&tx=107&ty=158&page=1&tbnh=169&tbnw=91&start=0&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:13,s:0&biw=1280&bih=666)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use: (in viewDidLoad)

```
   self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.opaque = NO;
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:.55];
```

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but it gives you the option to make everything clear. (obviously the alpha would change for your case, but that measures theo pacity of the cells)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Changing Alpha value will affect only the cell's background alone. I'm asking about table view's background's transparency. When you present a view/table view modally, the line `self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` or setting a alpha value for `self.tableView` does not works. :(

Comment: so you want the background to be the previous page with, say 50% alpha, to give it the effect like its 'popped up'?

Comment: what about [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008246/how-to-create-a-uitableviewcell-with-a-transparent-background). The code is something like: UIView *backView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = backView;

Answer (score 1):

Just altering the tableView doesn't help. You have to mess with the cells also. Inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method, put this before the return statement:

```
UIView * bgView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = bgView;
```

Comment: Using your code just hides the cells. But i want to reduce the opacity of UITableView's background