# How can I make a transparent background for selected cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

How can I make the cells transparent. I only want to show the selected cells with a checkmark which I have done:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } 
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

and when I first create the cells I do that next line of code to get rid of the blue background

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

but I have a weird issue where it takes 2 clicks to add and remove the checkboxes.  Maybe this is not the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about making transparent `UITableViewCell`s here: [How to create a UITableViewCell with a transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008246/how-to-create-a-uitableviewcell-with-a-transparent-background)

And as to your second issue, it appears that this is perhaps what you actually want:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: The transparent background code that I added was good but the second part of what you showed me was what I needed