# How make UITableView transparent

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying several solution like this to make my UITableView transparent

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath        indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      tableView.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("signCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SignUpTableViewCell


    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.signInfo.text="Mee"

   return cell
}
```

and I make my text transparent also, but the table and text after that disappear .

Comment: se ths once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008246/how-to-create-a-uitableviewcell-with-a-transparent-background

Comment: tableView.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I want solution in swift

Comment: @Chirag Patel this is what i do , the table and text is  disappear  I just want table transparent

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in ViewDidLoad

```
_tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

In some situations, setting **tableView.backgroundColor** doesn't work and the background of the tableView is always white. I came across this issue when using a UITableView within a custom UIView and solved it with this:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```